# UIView window is nil while being visible

Tags: uiview, uikit, uiwindow, xcode7, layoutsubviews

I have a UIView and when I tried updating its subviews alphas and frames I could't succeed. I checked the views `window` property and found its nil. What should I do fix it?

I have already tried all the:
`-layoutSubviews`, 
`-layoutSublayers`, 
`-setNeedsDisplay`, 
`-bringSubviewToFront:`, etc. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that when you declare it you are creating a UIView.

```
@IBOutlet var youUIView: UIView! = UIView()
```